# Is this grammar well-defined? How do I prove the language generated by it is regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata

I have the following problem statement:
[image]

Is G well-defined here? I am unsure of this since there's no production rule for $X, Y, Z$, and this confuses me a bit.

And secondly, how do I prove $L$ is regular? I was thinking the grammar might be right-linear, but I'm not sure if this is the case. Do you have any ideas on how to build an automaton that recognizes this language?

According to the solutions manual, this should be regular, but no proof is given. Also, they don't seem to consider that $L = \{ \lambda \}$.

[image]

Comment: Inserting essential information as an image prejudices potential responders in two ways: first, the information is inaccessible to people dependent on screen readers and other adaptive technologies or trying to read with a mobile phone, and secondly it makes it impossible to copy and paste into an answer. Please take this into account when asking questions.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: @D.W. thanks for your observation. I'll try to do that later. Regarding referencing, however -- this is from an exam question, unfortunately. It's not published material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the supplied solution, it's clear that the question was written incorrectly. The fifth, sixth and seventh productions should produce $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, respectively, instead of $A$, $B$ and $C$. You might want to report this typo to whomever set the problem.

Once you make that change, the fact that it is equivalent to a right-linear grammar can be shown by substituting $A$, $B$ and $C$ with their respective right-hand sides ($a$, $b$ and $c$).

Comment: one minor thing: if those production rules are for $X, Y, Z$ instead, the equivalent grammar would be left-linear, right?

Comment: @UncleSam: After you replace $A$, $B$ and $C$ as indicated, you get, for example, $X\to \lambda\mid bY\mid cZ$ which is certainly right-linear (non-terminal is the rightmost symbol on the right-hand side). (I would have done all that explicitly in the first place if I'd been able to copy and paste the question.)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the formal definition of grammars, there is nothing requiring  a nonterminal symbol to apppear in the left side of a production rule.
So $G$ is a perfectly valid grammar.

If we drop all useless production we are left with $S \to \lambda$. Therefore $L(G) = \{ \lambda\}$, which is a finite language and hence it is also regular. If you really want to, it is easy to come up with a DFA that recognizes this language.

Comment: but A, B, C --> _a_, _b_, _c_ (last production rules).

Comment: @UncleSam Steven meant that there is no production rule for $X,Y,Z$ and hence you will never reach a fully terminal string if you have them.

Comment: @nirshahar hmm, but that seems to go against the given solution. I updated the original post.

Comment: @UncleSam currently Steven answered the question correctly (as it is stated). From the additional info you have provided, it looks like they forgot to add production rules for $X,Y,Z$, since otherwise the third question does not make any sense.

Comment: @nirshahar To be pedantic, in the current statement, both b1 and b2 are correct answers to the third question since $s_0 = 1$ and all $s_i = 0$ for all $i \ge 1$. This clearly not what the designer of the questions had in mind, though.